# MySQL: Why is update trigger working and similar insert trigger not

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create two triggers (insert and update) that will calculate a price for a session with a client and then store it in the session table.

The update trigger works and I don't understand why the insert trigger doesn't work on the same principle (trigger has no effect).

Update Trigger:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER triggerCalculateTotalAfterUpdateSession
BEFORE UPDATE
ON session FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE TOTAL decimal(13,2);
IF (OLD.session_units <> new.session_units or OLD.therapist_id <> new.therapist_id or OLD.codeOfService_id <> new.codeOfService_id)  THEN
set NEW.session_total = (
        select
            if(
                NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 8
                or NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 10
                or NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 13
                or NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 22
                or NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 23,
                `rates`.`rates_rate`,
                NEW.`session_units` * `rates`.`rates_rate`
            ) AS `total`
        from
            (
                (
                    `session`
                    left join `therapist` on(
                        NEW.`therapist_id` = `therapist`.`therapist_id`
                    )
                )
                left join `rates` on(
                    NEW.`codeOfService_id` = `rates`.`codeOfService_id`
                    and `therapist`.`level_id` = `rates`.`level_id`
                )
            )where session.session_id = NEW.session_id
    );

END IF;
END
```

Insert Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerCalculateTotalAfterInsertSession
before INSERT
ON session FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
set NEW.session_total = (
        select
            if(
                NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 8
                or NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 10
                or NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 13
                or NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 22
                or NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 23,
                `rates`.`rates_rate`,
                NEW.`session_units` * `rates`.`rates_rate`
            ) AS `total`
        from
            (
                (
                    `session`
                    left join `therapist` on(
                        NEW.`therapist_id` = `therapist`.`therapist_id`
                    )
                )
                left join `rates` on(
                    NEW.`codeOfService_id` = `rates`.`codeOfService_id`
                    and `therapist`.`level_id` = `rates`.`level_id`
                )
            )where session.session_id = NEW.session_id
    );

END
```

[Table Structure session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrCrh.png)

[Table Structure therapist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mNwk.png)

[Table Structure rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxdxy.png)

Comment: You use a subquery to the table `session` which this trigger is defined on. When BEFORE UPDATE is fired the currently processed row already exists in the table and hence is processed in the subquery. Whereas when BEFORE INSERT is fired the currently processed row is absent in the table yet and is not processed in the subquery.

Comment: Investigate: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bade213e15f8f688241957fba5f81395

Answer (score 0):

I solved it the following way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerCalculateTotalAfterInsertSession before
INSERT
    ON session FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
set
    NEW.session_total = (
        select
            if(
                NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 8
                or NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 10
                or NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 13
                or NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 22
                or NEW.`codeOfService_id` = 23,
                `rates`.`rates_rate`,
                NEW.`session_units` * `rates`.`rates_rate`
            ) AS `total`
        from
            `rates`
            left join therapist on NEW.therapist_id = therapist.therapist_id
        where
            NEW.`codeOfService_id` = `rates`.`codeOfService_id` and rates.level_id = therapist.level_id 
    );
END
```